# Hibernate collection lazy load strange behavior

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a very strange problem, hibernate makes UPDATE query without any reasons.

I use Spring + Hibernate. Hibernate config:

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

My Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bId")
    private List<B> list;

 }

-----------------------

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B{

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private int test;
}
```

I get instance of A in my Transactional DAO, and after use this method

```
A a = ... get from DAO
List<B> listB = a.getList();

for (B o : listB){
      ......
}
```

When Java try to get iterator (listB.iterator()) hibernate make this request:

```
Hibernate: update b set bId=null where bId=?
```

Comment: It seems that I found the [problem](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7971).
I returned to version 4.1.7.Final and everything works.

Comment: Put a clear answer of the solution and maybe someone with the same problem can be beneficed with it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found the [problem](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7971). I returned to version 4.1.7.Final and everything works.

It's problem also fixed in 5.0.0, 4.3.5, 4.2.12 versions.